# not able to pass the selected values through Ajax

Tags: ajax

[This is the script i use for the drop down in the echo table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVD0u.png)

[The echo table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWdYj.png)

Comment: echo "<td>";
  
            echo "<a>". '<select name="cars"  class="drop1">';
                echo '<option value="Resolved">Resolved</option>';
                echo '<option value="Pending">Pending</option>';
                echo '<option value="Cased">Cased</option>';
                echo '<option value="Resolved" selected>Resolved</option>';
            echo "</select>" . "</a>";
   
        echo "</td>";

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
$('a').on('change', function(){


var data1 = {cars: $(".drop1").val()}


$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "data.php",
data: data1,


success: function(html)
{
$("#load").html(html);
}
});
return false;
});
});

Comment: can anyone help plz

Comment: Comments are supposed to be used for comments, not parts of code. Please add relevant code in your question text, so we don't have to click outside links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing your data object as text

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "data.php",
  data: JSON.stringify(data1) // use JSON.stringify();
});
```

Also a note is to make sure your html is echo'd or rendered out before you attempt to bind a javascript function to it. Other wise you will get an error indicating no such html element found.